# Single object, multiple IBOutlets

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, interface-builder

I've found discussion of dealing with a single IBOutlet and multiple objects but what about the reverse?  I have a single object I want to assign multiple IBOutlets to, are there any pitfalls there especially around releasing the IBOutlets in dealloc/viewDidUnload?

EDIT: For example...

I have a ViewController class that uses a different XIB for iPad and iPhone (its a custom CameraView controller).  Now on the iPhone there are 2 different labels for zoomLevel and videoDuration, on the iPad I use the same label for both, so in the iPad XIB I'd like to point the two IBOutlets to the same UILabel.

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you want to do? For example, maybe there is a single UILabel object used by multiple outlets? I only ask to help get the creative juices flowing!

Comment: So in the iPad version, is only one of the labels (zoomLevel and videoDuration) visible at any one time? Or will both ever be displayed at once?

Comment: On the either device only one is being used at a time (I don't allow zooming a video) so by using 2 IBOutlets to the same label it allows all the logic used for the iPhone to also be used on the iPad.

Comment: When you display one of the shared labels, are you reinitializing it? (Setting the text at least, maybe other properties as well)

Comment: Yup, I'm setting the text, alpha and hidden properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe each outlet assigned to the object would raise the retain count by 1, and as you set the outlets to nil when the view unloads the count would be decremented by 1 each time, so it should work

Since you have to reinitialize properties each time the view is displayed I would say a pitfall is the view display logic has been removed from the XIB and put into your code. I would say the severity of this is subject to personal opinion and how religious you want to maintain the MVC relationship.

Comment: This is also how I assume it should work, provided nobody points out an issue this seems right :)